# TypeError: addslashes(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string after upgrade Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

TypeError: addslashes(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, null given in vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:440

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information. When does this error occur? What's the stack trace? It appears that `null` is passed to the escaper.

Comment: @Daniel This error occurs when we had run the website after the upgrade. I have also checked not to show any third-party module error.

Answer (score 4):

Without modify core code - simple update the core_config_data table with this sql statement:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'welcome' WHERE path ='design/header/welcome'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution: Add the below line in the di.xml file.**

```
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" type="Vendor\Packagename\Block\Html\Header" />
```

**Create a new Header.php file under the Vendor\Packagename\Block\Html folder.**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Packagename\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Html page header block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Header extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header
{
    /**
     * @var Escaper
     */
    private $escaper;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param Escaper|null $escaper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        Escaper $escaper = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data, $escaper);
        $this->escaper = $escaper ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Escaper::class);
    }

    /**
     * Current template name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml';

    /**
     * Retrieve welcome text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWelcome()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'design/header/welcome',
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
        }
        return $this->escaper->escapeQuote(__($this->_data['welcome'])->render(), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**File : vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Header.php**

**Replace from**

> $this->_data['welcome'] =
> $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('design/header/welcome',
> ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
> );

**To**

> $this->_data['welcome'] = (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
> 'design/header/welcome',
> ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
> );

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37208

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is designed to escape quotes, and it uses the addslashes() function to add backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. If $addSlashes is set to true, the addslashes() function is called on $data.

To avoid the TypeError, you could add a conditional check to ensure $data is not null before calling addslashes():

Go to file /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php > go to line 437
and replace this code

public function escapeQuote($data, $addSlashes = false)
{
if ($addSlashes === true) {
$data = addslashes($data);
}
return htmlspecialchars($data, $this->htmlSpecialCharsFlag, null, false);
}

With this code

> public function escapeQuote($data, $addSlashes = false)
> {
> if ($data !== null) {
> if ($addSlashes === true) {
> $data = addslashes($data);
> }
> } else {
> // Optionally, handle null values here, or log them for debugging
> $data = '';
> }
> return htmlspecialchars($data, $this->htmlSpecialCharsFlag, null, false);
> }

Save file
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Issue Resolved!